# Spark graphX: how to load big data to create a graph

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I see a lot of examples using array to create vertex first then parallelize it to make it a RDD, but if I have huge data then how would I handle it? I don't think I can create an array of say 1 million rows of vertex.

There is another post, [Spark GraphX - How can I read from a JSON file in Spark and create a graph from the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334116/spark-graphx-how-can-i-read-from-a-json-file-in-spark-and-create-a-graph-from), also suggested to use array as well, correct me if I am wrong but again I don't think it would work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you data in a file, then you can directly create rdd on top of it:

```
val rdd : RDD[String] = sparkContext.textFile("/path/to/file")
```

and then your transform it to VertexRDD or EdgeRDD.